# Join importxml & importhtml by braces

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

This formula is in `A1`:

```
=
{
{"LINK DA FOTO","LINK DO PERFIL"}
;
{"LINK DA FOTO","LINK DO PERFIL"}
;
ArrayFormula(SEERRO(PROCH(1,{1;IMPORTXML('Time Casa'!B12,"//table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='photo']/a/img/@src | //table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='name large-link']/a/@href")},(LIN($A$1:$A$52)+1)*2-TRANSPOR(sort(LIN($A$1:$A$2)+0,1,0)))))
}
```

This formula is in `C1`:

```
=
{TRANSPOR(IMPORTXML(
'Time Casa'!B12,"
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th/img/@title | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[6]/span | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[5] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[3] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[4] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[1] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[2]
"))
;
IMPORTHTML('Time Casa'!B12,"table","1")
}
```

Result:
[image]

By uniting like this in `Sheet2`, it works perfectly, the result is exactly that of the image above.

```
=
{
Sheet3!A:B
,
Sheet3!C:S
}
```

But when joining via the same formula I did below, it gives error and says ↓

> Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched line length. Expected 54
>   and have: 39.

```
=
{
{
{"LINK DA FOTO","LINK DO PERFIL"}
;
{"LINK DA FOTO","LINK DO PERFIL"}
;
ArrayFormula(SEERRO(PROCH(1,{1;IMPORTXML('Time Casa'!B12,"//table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='photo']/a/img/@src | //table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='name large-link']/a/@href")},(LIN($A$1:$A$52)+1)*2-TRANSPOR(sort(LIN($A$1:$A$2)+0,1,0)))))
}
,
{TRANSPOR(IMPORTXML(
'Time Casa'!B12,"
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th/img/@title | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[6]/span | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[5] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[3] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[4] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[1] | 
//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[2]
"))
;
IMPORTHTML('Time Casa'!B12,"table","1")
}
}
```

I would like to know what I need to adjust so it can work, I tried to use `=FILTER(X,X<>"")` but the same error continued.
Link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNhl5hf5ofST84nawfBF6kuzhn83UMldh1lS20VTJpA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={{{"LINK DA FOTO", "LINK DO PERFIL"};
   {"LINK DA FOTO", "LINK DO PERFIL"};
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(1, {1; IMPORTXML('Time Casa'!B12, 
 "//table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='photo']/a/img/@src | 
  //table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='name large-link']/a/@href")},
 (ROW($A$1:$A$52)+1)*2-TRANSPOSE(SORT(ROW($A$1:$A$2)+0, 1, 0)))), 
 "where Col1 is not null"))},
 {TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML('Time Casa'!B12,
 "//*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th/img/@title | 
  //*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[6]/span | 
  //*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[5] | 
  //*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[3] | 
  //*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[4] | 
  //*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[1] | 
  //*[@id='page_team_1_block_team_squad_3-table']/thead/tr/th[2]"));
 IMPORTHTML('Time Casa'!B12, "table", "1")}}
```

[image: 0]